# Configure the load balancer's proxy to write the client's source IP

Tags: asp.net

I have an Asp.net web application in which I need to get the IP of the client's machine. I have used the following code for getting the IP:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

After the installation of the load balancer, we are getting the load balancer's IP instead of the IP the user is at. After some analysis, I found that we need to configure the load balancer and then we we will be able to read the client's IP by using the following code:

```
Request.ServerVariables(`X-Forwarded-For`)
```

My question is how to configure the load balancer?

Comment: Which load balancer are you using?

Comment: It's not really an asp.net question, as it's a question about the configuration of the loadbalancer